# Apache: include htaccess in conf with AllowOverride None, better performance?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Suppose we have the `/home/example.org/public_html/` directory on the filesystem, which serves as the document root of my virtualhost.

The relevant httpd configuration for that vhost would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org:80
  ...
  DocumentRoot /home/example.org/public_html
  <Directory /home/example.org/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    ...
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

In order to prevent the htaccess lookups on the filesystem without losing the htaccess functionality – at least at the DocumentRoot level- I transformed the configuration to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org:80
  ...
  DocumentRoot /home/example.org/public_html
  <Directory /home/example.org/public_html>
    AllowOverride None
    Include /home/example.org/public_html/.htaccess
    ...
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Difference

```
AllowOverride None
Include /home/example.org/public_html/.htaccess
```

Let’s see what we have accomplished with this:

> httpd does not waste any time looking for and parsing htaccess files
>   resulting in faster request processing

Questions:

1. Using `Include` directive, Apache load htaccess only on service start or for each request?
2. If point 1 it's true, how do refresh apache conf without `httpd.exe -k restart`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache accesses and processes the htaccess files on each request. This is why one does not need to restart the server every time to check their current configurations.

You do need to restart the server/service for testing any changes made to `apache.conf`, `httpd.conf` or the vhost configurations.

---

Quoting from [Apache's tutorial on `htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file:

> You should avoid using `.htaccess` files completely if you have access
>   to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down
>   your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a
>   `.htaccess` file is better set in a `Directory` block, as it will have
>   the same effect with better performance.

---

Since you already are trying to `Include` the `htaccess` from inside a `<Directory>` module block, the performance would be better if you include everything from the file to this block itself instead. There is, although no difference; apart from having to maintain configurations in two places simultaneously.

The `htaccess` file will get processed just once, at the time of server start.

Comment: sorry, point 1 isn't clear.. correct question is: Using `Include` directive,  Apache load htaccess only on service start or for each request?

Comment: While this addresses some parts of the question, you're essentially not addressing the overall intent as asked.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, note that checking for .htaccess is commonly not all that big an issue, since the relevant bits of the disk are cached in memory.  It becomes an issue where for example you have a very large number of directories under your web root directory or directories, and the hits are scattered amongst them so that the hit rate on cached disk blocks is low.  You might be better dealing with that by disabling `.htaccess` selectively for directory trees where it creates a problem.  Parsing the .htaccess directives creates a little CPU load of course, but CPU should generally not be your server's bottleneck.

Answering your question as posed though; Yes, you will need to run a command as root to load the new configuration.  Rather than using `restart` though, use `reload` or (better) `graceful`.

```
httpd.exe -k graceful
```

You could (but probably shouldn't) write a cron job to periodically check whether this needs to be run.  Without a lot of testing, I think something like this should work, run as a regular root cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ /var/run/httpd/http.pid -nt /home/example.org/public_html/.htaccess ] \
  && httpd.exe -k graceful
```

This creates a bit of disk load itself of course.  This load doesn't increase with traffic volume, but might be an issue if you have many such included files.

SECURITY WARNING:  It sounds like you are setting up a situation where a non root user is likely to be able to get Apache to `Include` directives at will.  This is much more powerful than what can be done with a `.htaccess` file, and amounts to a root exploit.  E.g. it gives access to things like the `User` and `LoadModule` directives, which .htaccess directives can never do.

I recommend that you should put `Included` directives in a file inside your Apache configuration directory, and have it accessible only by root.  There are other ways to make sure that only root can edit the .htaccess file, but getting these files out of the user-owned area makes it less likely you'll inadvertently open access again later.

While the `.htaccess` mechanism does incur extra disk load, it is the mechanism that's designed for use by non-root users.  It would be nice to have a mechanism for untrusted users to modify configuration with a limit on how often the .htaccess file would be checked for, but if it exists, I don't know it.